# How can I validate inputs against Regex using .every() method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have a function `getSum()`. I have two date inputs and I am trying to validate, before a piece of code is run. I have an if statement and the condition is a `.every` on the inputs array. I need to pass in a function which matches BOTH input values to the Regex, before the code is executed.

I'm quite confused.

```
var sumButton = 
document.querySelector(".sumNumbers");
sumButton.addEventListener("click", getSum);

var dateRegEx = /^(19|20)\d{2}-(0\d{1}|1[0-2])-([0- 
2]\d{1}|3[0-1])$/;

var removeErrorMsg = 
document.querySelectorAll(".resetError");
removeErrorMsg.addEventListener("click", function() 
{

document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = 
"";
})




function getSum() {
let inputs = ['dateInput1', 'dateInput2'];
let outputs = ['result1', 'result2'];


if (inputs.every(function(){

})) {
  inputs.forEach(function(input, index) {
    const inputValue = 
document.getElementById(input).value;

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
        const num = parseInt(inputValue.charAt(i));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            sum += num;
        }
    }
    const total = (sum - 1) % 9 + 1;


document.getElementById(outputs[index]).textContent 
= "Your number is: " + total;

});
} else{
  document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = 
"*error* please enter two dates and two names"
}

// 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `every` method accepts a callback which is passed each element of the array that `every` was called on, if all of the return values from the callback are `true`, then `every` returns `true`, otherwise, `every` returns `false`.

So you just need to write a callback function to pass to `every` that accepts a single element of the `inputs` array and returns a boolean. To test against a regular expression, we can use the regex `test` method, which returns `true` if the given string matches the regex pattern and `false` otherwise.

For example:

```js
function dateIsValid(dateString) {
    return dateRegEx.test(dateString);
}
```

In context:

```js
if (inputs.every(dateIsValid)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or with an inline definition:

```js
if (inputs.every(dateString => dateRegEx.test(dateString))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but i dont think i am extracting the numerical value from the inputs arrays. Am I? I had to do that in the forEach, further down in the function. I need to extract the values of both somehow. this isnt working

Comment: is dateString just a placeholder?

Comment: @nineborn if you just want to check if all the elements of `inputs` match the regex pattern, then this approach will work. If you want to extract values using regex capture, you'd probably be better with a `map` call. And `dateString` is a variable name, but you can change it to anything you want.